# Hoko Links for Android - app is freezing

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have implemented Hokolinks (Deeplinking) in an Android app
and am now facing an issue:

- App is lagging or freezes after clicking on links a second time.
- Overall hangs my whole device process after I click on generated smart links.

Can anyone suggest why this is happening?

```
Hoko.setup(this, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxcd");   
Hoko.deeplinking().mapRoute("HOKOlink/:product_id", new DeeplinkCallback() {
    @Override
    public void deeplinkOpened(Deeplink deeplink) {
        Constant.deepLinkProductId = deeplink.getRouteParameters().get("product_id");
    }
});
```

**Reference :** [www.hokolinks.com](http://www.hokolinks.com)

Comment: Suggest me something before low my vote :(

Comment: Some people simply like a downvoting from no reason (they feel more important), let me fix that.